# Handling Multiple Tables with Large amount of Data with Cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

HI recently i am working with kind of large project
I have 5 tables which needs to work with. 
This is my scenario
I want to List All the Posts in posts table and all comments for particular  post. each comment has author, so I need there information too.
to make it easy

Post 1

-> Post Description [Take from posts table]

-> Comments related to post 1[Take from Comments table, also has post_id as foreign key]

-> Commented user Information [Comment table has user_id as Foreign key]

Post 2

-> Post Description [Take from posts table]

-> Comments related to post 2[Take from Comments table, also has post_id as foreign key]

-> Commented user Information [Comment table has user_id as Foreign key]

.

.

.

Post {n}

-> Post Description [Take from posts table]

-> Comments related to post {n}[Take from Comments table, also has post_id as foreign key]

-> Commented user Information [Comment table has user_id as Foreign key]

Assume i have over 10000 posts in my table

Can any one help me to work with this.

Also I thought to create table view from the Database layer to do this task

Comment: Please show your existing find call, a relevant summary of the sql log and state the version of cake you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have your [Model relations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) set up correctly (I won't go into detail on this because the CakePHP book is an excellent reference on the matter), this is relatively simple.

To be able to get User data for each comment post as well, you'll have to use [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html). Again, I won't really explain what it does because the book can do it better.

I'm providing a sample query below, though be cautioned it may not be 100% correct (especially considering I do not know the names of your columns):

```
$data = $this->Post->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('Post.description'),
    'contains' => array(
        'Comments',
        'Commenter' //Alias for the User Model
    )  
    ));
```

Just an explaination of the comment above: This assumes `Comment hasOne Commenter => array('className' => 'User')`

Comment: Wouldn't that be somewhat efficient considering the amount of data OP wants from the query? I guess if OP custom wrote a JOIN they could get a higher efficiency but that would be rather complex.

Comment: Well, what is it you're suggesting to do that's different than how cake works by default? Alternatively can you think of a less efficient way to do it :)? In any event, I double checked and that would generate 1 query for posts, 1 query for comments and one query **per comment** to get the user name. That's better (maybe) than I expected, but not optimal. Note that 1) the key for containable is `contain`, 2) model names are singlular (`Comments`) 3) Commenter would belong to Comment - the contain array is not nested correctly.

Comment: [Here's an example showing the query log](https://gist.github.com/AD7six/e84aa17eaa02f77ab79f) - indicating that the number of queries is 2 + the number of comments.